# For Loop Iterating last Value only in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, loop

I have a SObject list that I am iterating through, so my var="standardOppFields"

I created a loop to generate a value for each opportunity. I want to display both the standard fields AND the custom value in the same visual force table. 
Is this possible?

```
openOpps = new List<Opportunity>([Select id,Name, Account.Phone,Account.Id,Postal_Code__c,
                                     (Select contact.Name 
                                      From OpportunityContactRoles where role='Primary') 
                                  From Opportunity 
                                  where (ownerId=:UserInfo.getUserId()]);


 Map<String, String> zipToTimeZoneMap = new Map<String, String>();
   for(Opportunity o :openOpps){
     localTime = system.Now().addHours(d).format('hh:mm a');
   }
```

on my VF page, I'm using this format

```
<apex:column value="{!openOpps.Postal_Code__c}">
   <apex:facet name="header">  
     <apex:commandLink action="{!openOpps}"> 
       <apex:param value="Postal_Code__c" name="column" ></apex:param>
     </apex:commandLink>
   </apex:facet>
</apex:column>
```

When I try to do the same VF format with the localTime variable, it's taking the last value in the loop every time.

Comment: It sounds possible but we can't help you without more information. Can you post what you have so far and where you are stuck?

Comment: Please post code.

Comment: @BarCotter I have added the code snippets.

Comment: What is your question? Are you having problems displaying standard and custom fields? Where is `standardOppFields` being used in the code? How does `localTime` come in to this?

Comment: This is a classic wrapper class use case. Basically you need to wrap up the local time value and the Opportunity into a plain Apex class and iterate over that. Lot's of docs on this. Start here: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get every time the last value is because you probably have only a single one localTime object or property defined, which you are overwriting again and again in the loop.

Since the page markup is composed after the apex loop has finished, no wonder that all cells in the column end up the same.

We can't tell this for sure, because we miss that part of your code, but it's my guess.

The wrapper pattern metioned by @Peter should solve this by introducing one localTime value per record.